# Relationship based Taxonomies Dropdown

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Please help.

I am very new to web development & don't have any computers background. I have created a pincodes database Website pincodes.forinfo.in using WordPress. I want a relationship based dropdown Taxonomies like www.pincode.city.

I have tried many ways from last 6 months but failed. Please help me.

I have custom Taxonomies State, District, City, pincode. I need a taxonomy dropdown, when user clicked on state the second dropdown should show the Districts of that particular state. Like wise when a user clicked on District the third dropdown should show the cities of the particular.

How can it is possible. Please help me.
I want show this dropdown on a WordPress page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Wordpress then I do not see the reason to be baffled by this, since you will be able to manage this from Appearance->Menu.

Check out my screenshots.

1. Click on the Screen Options button on the top right corner of the
   Menu page. [Screen Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69fMk.png)
2. For me, Types is a custom Taxonomy, so I select it. The taxonomies appear on the left now [Custom Tax Appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22fsT.png)

You can now add the links to your menu and then arrange it so that it becomes a sub-menu of your primary menu.

Comment: There are 1,50, 000 posts & not possible for creating a dropdown menu. I want a dropdown search on front page. Please check www.pincodes.city for reference.

Comment: Well, honestly, what you are looking for is a good deal of code to implement what they have in pincode.city. It is definitely possible, but I will need to query and play around with your Wordpress installation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I would send the login details. Apart from this is there any WordPress plugin. Available for chained dropdown taxonomy search.

Comment: I do not think so. At least, I am not aware of any. I had looked for an autocomplete a long time back. Now, there is https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/ and a few more plugins...but I do not think there are any to fit your specific purpose...if you do find any, please let me know...and always there to help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how your menu should look if you want your custom taxonomy to be a sub-item of another menu item.

[Sub menu items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4329.png)

You can do this by holding and dragging the item slightly to the right.

You can stack such items one below the other and create endless sub-menus.

I must mention that there are some themes that do not support sub-menus. If you theme doesn't, change it and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Things that you need to do to implement your idea:

1. Get a good autocomplete plugin - [Easyautocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/) (Much better than jQuery UI autocomplete)
2. Create three input boxes on a custom template page
3. Use enqueue_script to get your JS files to load with your Wordpress installation
4. Bind autocomplete to the three input text boxes
5. Learn how to query your Wordpress installation for your taxonomies
6. Use a php file to transfer a json file of your taxonomies to the autocomplete function - I would recommend [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) AJAX plugin
7. Have conditions in your php file according to which the 2nd field's values are fetched after getting the value of the first field and similarly for the third field

As I said, it's a lot of coding, and if you are really starting out to code this yourself, without much knowledge of PHP or jQuery, it's going to be very difficult. I would suggest you take the help of a developer.

You can even send me the details of logging into your Wordpress installation, if you want me to take a look.

Mail me at arunadaybasu@gmail.com